# woocommerce add to cart button disabled when you click 'back' from add to cart page

Tags: wordpress, firefox, woocommerce

This a problem on Firefox, works fine on Chrome. If you add a product to the cart, then click back to the product page, (rather than clicking 'continue shopping') the add to cart button now has the attribute 'disabled' added to it. 
Anyone know why this is or how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here -
[firefox - autocomplete off](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

I added the attribute

```
    autocomplete="off"
```

to the form tag.

To do this in woocommerce:

Create a *woocommerce* directory(folder) in your wordpress child theme.

In this woocommerce folder, create a *single-product* folder, in here, yet another folder, *add-to-cart*.

Then copy the files, *simple.php* and *variable.php*, from the original woocommerce directory, which is in *wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart*
(notice you don't copy the templates directory in your child theme. I have no idea why.)

Open simple.php and variable.php and add the 'autocomplete="off" attribute.

Comment: Your link states that "*The ability for websites to disable the password manager using autocomplete = "off"  is being removed in Firefox 30*", so (assuming users keep up-to-date with the frenetic Firefox release rate) this might not work much after Firefox 30 is released ([June 10, 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history), apparently).

Comment: I know, saw that, but since I got no answer, I thought I'd put in the one that works for now